# Facebook FQL UNION operation

Tags: sql, facebook, union, facebook-fql

Could you please anyone can show the UNION operation of two SELECT statements results in FQL.
When i was trying to execute FQL query with UNION operation, I'm getting the following error error_msg=Parser error: unexpected 'UNION' at position 171., error_code=601}.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

facebook don't support union in fql.

You can use [fql multi query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/)